# How do I run inspectdb against different schemas in oracle?

Tags: django, oracle, inspectdb

I want to run [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) against an Oracle database. The user account that I use is a read only user that owns 0 tables. It, however, has access to the schema that contains all the tables. How do I specify a schema when using `inspectdb`?

My command, currently, is: `python manage.py inspectdb --database "oradb" > test_model.py`

This only outputs a file with `from django.db import models`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

César's answer is true regarding Oracle support. However, I was able to generate a rough model by modifying `django\db\backends\oracle\introspection.py` in two places.

Change the `cursor.execute` line in `get_table_list` to read:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'OTHERSCHEMA'")
```

Change the `user_table_cols` to `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` in the first `cursor.execute` line in `get_table_description` to read:

```
cursor.execute("""
        SELECT
            column_name,
            data_default,
            CASE
                WHEN char_used IS NULL THEN data_length
                ELSE char_length
            END as internal_size
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = UPPER(%s)""", [table_name])
```

Next, change the second `cursor.execute` line in `get_table_description` to read: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM OTHERSCHEMA.%s WHERE ROWNUM < 2" % self.connection.ops.quote_name(table_name))`

Since this is a legacy database where policy prevents changes to the database, this was good for a one time run.

A few more changes are needed once the model is complete. It appears a few of my classes are missing primary key references and foreign key references. I will add these manually.

The last change I made was to modify all of the `class Meta:` instances to reference the correct schema:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = u'"SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"'     # Notice the quoting needed
```

Comment: It works for me. After using inspectdb i revert back changes. I used db_column in models so that django recognise ForeignKeys correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Django's [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) doesn't support Oracle. From the docs:

> inspectdb works with PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite. Foreign-key
>   detection only works in PostgreSQL and with certain types of MySQL
>   tables.
>
> The --database option may be used to specify the database to
>   introspect.

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone comes upon this thread: Andy's suggestions + I've also changed the get_relations method to get foreign keys in the generated source, works in 1.9.1:

```
    def get_relations(self, cursor, table_name):
    """
    Returns a dictionary of {field_name: (field_name_other_table, other_table)}
    representing all relationships to the given table.
    """
    table_name = table_name.upper()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT a.column_name, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
          FROM all_cons_columns a
          JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                                AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
          JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                                   AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
         WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
           AND a.table_name = %s""", [table_name])

    relations = {}
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        relations[row[0].lower()] = (row[2].lower(), row[1].lower())
    return relations
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents in. (django version 1.9.7 + django GIS extension)

Following Andy and Mirek Simek suggestions I further modified:

added *'schemas'* in your db config in **settings.py**

```
    ...
    'oracle1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
        'HOST': 'dbhostname',
        'PORT': 'dbport',
        'schemas': ['SCHEMANAME1', ....] #<-- this
    }, 
    ...
```

modified **get_tables_list** in this way:

```
def get_table_list(self, cursor):
    """
    Returns a list of table and view names in the current database.
    """
    cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME, 't' FROM USER_TABLES UNION ALL "
                   "SELECT VIEW_NAME, 'v' FROM USER_VIEWS")
    res = [TableInfo(row[0].lower(), row[1]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    schemas = self.connection.settings_dict.get('schemas')
    if schemas and len(schemas)>0:
        for s in schemas:
            cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME, 't' FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = '%s'" %s)
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                tbl_name, typ = '.'.join([s,row[0].lower()]), row[1]
                try:
                    # let us check for permission to query
                    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ROWNUM < 1" % tbl_name.upper())
                except DatabaseError, e:
                    pass
                else:
                    res.append(TableInfo(tbl_name, typ))
    return res
```

Cause I'm using gis I had to make a dirty patch (I don't know if it is needed due to database issue) to **django/contrib/gis/db/backends/oracle/introspection.py**

just added this at the end of **get_geometry_type**

```
    ...
        dim = len(dim)
        if dim != 2:
            field_params['dim'] = dim
    except:  # <-- this
        pass # <-- this
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to specify the search_path, by adding an option in your DATABASES variable at settings.py, like that:

```
'OPTIONS': {
       'options': '-c search_path=myschema'
}
```

The full DATABASES variable should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=myschema'
        }
    }
}
```

After that `python migrate inspectdb` should work on your schema

Comment: The question was how to inspect schemas in Oracle, not Postgresql.